How can I get the Breakpoints window back into the Run and Debug sidebar?
I accidentally moved the Breakpoints window out of the Run and Debug sidebar, and now I can't find a way to move it back in.
I moved it out as I was trying to resize it because it had become tiny somehow and I couldn't find a place to hover my mouse to grab the border and move it.

Just click and drag on the Breakpoints title when you have the Run and Debug view open and drop it there
